# What will be the best way to parse and manipulate Liquid templates like DOM?

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, liquid

I want to manipulate liquid templates to add new html nodes and conditions dynamically in the way similar to inserting new nodes in nokogiri or JavaScript to dom. What would be the easiest way to implement such feature?

My ideas:

- Using regex
- Creating pseudo markup such that I would have for each line in the template(my pseudo code follows):

  ```
  <div class="my-class"> transform into HtmlNode.new(:start, :div, { class:'my-class' })
  ```

For liquid something along this lines(pseudo code)

```
{{ page.title }} transform into LiquidNode.new(:object, 'page.title' )
```

That would be array, then I could insert my code at specific index and convert it back to liquid template

I don't think it's a new problem but I can't find easy solution anywhere in the internet. Maybe I can't name the problem properly.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't manipulate the compiled output? Trying to dynamically alter liquid templates is not a trivial problem.

Comment: I can't as I want to introduce dynamic condition and manipulating compiled output doesn't help me at all.